Converting the following recursive binary tree traversal algorithm to an iterative one
I would like to learn whether the following recursive code can be made more efficient by an iterative implementation, and if so, how such implementation can be done. It has been some years since I have actively coded, so I have forgot enough nomenclature that I don't think I can answer this question myself with the help of existing literature.
Denote by land r the number of left and right turns we have taken in a binary tree of height n. Suppose that f(l, r) is some real function that computes some value depending on l and r in constant time. Assume that f is not symmetric, i.e. not necessarily f(l,r) = f(r,l). The recursive code is as follows (in Python 3):
def recursive_travel(l, r, cur_height, max_height):
    if cur_height == max_height:
       return f(l, r) * (f(l+1, r) + f(l, r+1))
    return recursive_travel(l+1, r, cur_height+1, max_height) + recursive_travel(l, r+1, cur_height+1, max_height)

and the initial call should be recursive_travel(0,0,0,n). Iterative implementation will be a slightly more faster without the need for recursive calls, but I don't know whether there is an elegant way to implement this. All help will be appreciated!

You can use dynamic programming to avoid recomputing overlapping subproblems. By storing the results of subproblems in a table, you can compute each value only once and reuse it when needed.
To reduce the number of calls to the function f(i, j), precompute the values and store them in a table. Then refer to the table whenever the value at a particular position (i, j) is required.
def iterative_travel(n):
    # Precompute values of f(i, j) and store them in a table
    f_table = [[f(i, j) for j in range(n + 1)] for i in range(n + 1)]

    # Initialize a table to store computed values
    dp = [[0] * (n + 1) for _ in range(n + 1)]

    # Fill the table bottom-up
    for i in range(n, -1, -1):
        for j in range(n, -1, -1):
            if i == n and j == n:
                dp[i][j] = f_table[i][j]
            elif i == n:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i][j + 1] * f_table[i][j]
            elif j == n:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j] * f_table[i][j]
            else:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i + 1][j] * f_table[i][j] + dp[i][j + 1] * f_table[i][j]

    return dp[0][0]

This approach ensures that each unique position (i, j) is computed only once, reducing the number of function calls and improving efficiency.
